# Access global function from within onEnded audio object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

console.log("setActiveWord", setActiveWord) shows the full function returned from useState(). However, console.log("setActiveWord2", setActiveWord) that executes when the audio has ended shows an empty function.

Would someone mind explaining to me why this is? I expected the nextRound function to have access to setActiveWord from the global scope.

```
const FlyingWords = () => {
const [activeWord, setActiveWord] = useState(false)
const {audios, createAudios} = useCreateGameAssets({})


function nextRound() {
    console.log("setActiveWord2", setActiveWord)
}
    
Object.keys(correctAudios).forEach(key => {
    console.log("setActiveWord", setActiveWord)
    correctAudios[key].onended = () => {correctSound.play(); nextRound(key)}
})
```

Comment: What is `correctAudios`?

Comment: An object of audio objects {a: <Audio />, b: <Audio />}

Comment: Where do these come from? Could their `onended` be overwritten by some other `FlyingWords` call that does have an empty `setActiveWord`?

Comment: No there are no other components called FlyingWords and nextRound is called fine.